# IE8 blocked this site from downloading files -- javascript window.open location discrepancy

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I manage an ASP.NET site where they want to open multiple reports at the click of a button (preferably each in its own tab). The reports are saved as URLs for now, so I just need to open multiple windows with those urls.

I am attempting to do so using javascript (namely window.open). Here is an example of what I am doing (though I removed the actual urls):

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="openLinks();return false;">Open both links</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openLinks(){
        var FirstWindow = window.open('');
        FirstWindow.location = 'https://myssrsReportURL/rs:Format=EXCEL';

        window.open('https://myssrsReportURL/rs:Format=EXCEL');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The first 2 lines of the js method above has the advantage of forcing the url to open in a new tab versus a new window. However, in the example above, when I set the location after opening a blank window, I receive the file download error IE "blocked this site from downloading":
[image]

Where as the second url opens (in a new window) without issue (I get a file download prompt).

Why does the second method work (I receive a file download prompt) while the first doesn't (I receive an IE security warning) if they are opening the same url? Is there some way around this using javascript (or jQuery)?

The customer is requiring that a single button click open all these reports. I can not zip them all up in one request because the reports are generated by SSRS upon a get request to a specific url (the ones I am attempting to open in new tabs).

**Note, the question is not, "how do I open multiple tabs"** it's why does the behavior discrepancy exist  between window.open('') versus window.open('url')

Comment: why not just specify `_blank` as the second parameter for `open`?

Comment: If the window opens with a download then IE will close the window again automatically anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no JavaScript magic trick to trick browsers into opening multiple tabs. And if there is...it will be stopped as it is a security vulnerability (download/tabs spam denial of service).

There is a better solution, which works on every browser. You can even choose between JavaScript and ASP.NET.

Create multiple iframe elements and show one at a time by using on-page tabs/links/buttons (simple onclick action to reveal one iframe and hide the rest). For downloads, this method has the advantage of not losing the current page if a server side script fails (so instead of 500 Internal Error or blank page the user remains on the current page).

For multiple downloads, why not zip the files on the server to have a single download prompt? It makes sense to not annoy users with many many download prompts.

Comment: See update. In short the customer is requiring all the reports to open at once. They can either open in html or in other formats (i.e. excel). The reports/files are not on our server, they are generated by an SSRS server and accessed via urls, that have specific report parameters, so one url generates one unique report. Thus the need for multiple windows.

Comment: @n00b So then open the URLs server side, zip them, serve one download. This also helps to keep the batch grouped on the user's desktop.